# ASP.NET GridView row count using Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, gridview

Having the GridView client control ID, I would like to get some ideas on how to count the GridView rows or at least be able to tell if there is at least one row on the Gridview the restriction is that I can only use client side code (JavaScript in this case)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
var rowscount = document.getElementByID('<%=Gridview1.ClientID%>').rows.length;

alert(rowscount);
```