# How Can I get grid.rows.count once the button been clicked?

Tags: c#, .net

I have tried to used the following code under the aspx.cs file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class pgTest : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblResult.Text = grid.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

But somehow this is always not get the gird rows count for me in the 1st clicked on the button, but then it will show up in the 2nd clicked on the button.

Exmaple:
If I manage to found 5 records in the 1st clicked, but then it will not show 5 on the screen until I clicked the button the 2nd time.

Does anyone know how can I solve this issue? how can I do it will only display the rows count on real time?

Comment: Be sure to Bind the grid before trying to count the number of rows it has.

Comment: I think this is right.  You don't show any databind before you read the grid.

Comment: how can I do so it will read the grid and display the count on screen in real time?

Answer (score 0):

Put that line of code in the button's click event handler instead of Page_Load.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblResult.Text = grid.Rows.Count.ToString();
    }
```

where Button1_Click would be the event handler for your button's click event.

Comment: won't that require postback to update?  If so, will he may need viewstate or session variable to save it, no?

Comment: I applied the code you have provided... but same issue happen :(

Comment: any way that I can code the rows count directly under asp:GridView??

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to do it real time... I think you should use `javascript`

Take a look at this question for [GridView Row Count using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763641/asp-net-gridview-row-count-using-javascript)