# How to check whether the check box inside Gridview Template is Selected or not with Javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a gridview which contains one templatefield checkbox to select the data for each row. Here they can select the members from the grid.

```
 <asp:GridView ID="dgMembers2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="chkBxHeader" onclick="javascript:HeaderClick(this);" runat="server"
                                Text="Select All" />
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Gridview>
```

So, when they select member and click on ADD then its inserting into the database but if they do not select any checkbox from the grid I cannot show any error message. Can anyone suggest please how I can check this with Javascript that whether they have checked at least one checkbox or not and then I want to show

```
Javascript Alert
```

I tried a lot but my field is template field so I do not know how to work with it.

Any suggestion will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to make Select All/UnSelect All

```
function HeaderClick(CheckBox, gdvClientId) {

var TargetBaseControl =     document.getElementById(gdvClientId);
            var TargetChildControl = 'chkOrder';


            var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName('input');


            for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
                if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&                                      Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0)
                    Inputs[n].checked = CheckBox.checked;

        }
```

Call the function from your headertemplate like this
`HeaderClick(CheckBox, gdvClientId)`,  gdvClientId is your Gridview ID

Comment: Thanks for your reply..actually I already have the Check/Uncheck facility but I want to impliment when user forget to check and click the button then one alret will be shown to them "Please select at least one check box"..

Comment: You can add the counter in condition
if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&                                      Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0)
                    Inputs[n].checked = CheckBox.checked;
to check if any checkbox is checked OR not.

Comment: I tried with the help of your code:

but nothing happening..is there anything I am missing?

Comment: function HeaderClick(CheckBox, gdvClientId) {

var TargetBaseControl =     document.getElementById(gdvClientId);
            var TargetChildControl = 'chkOrder';


            var Inputs = TargetBaseControl.getElementsByTagName('input');
var counter=0

            for (var n = 0; n < Inputs.length; ++n)
                if (Inputs[n].type == 'checkbox' &&                                      Inputs[n].id.indexOf(TargetChildControl, 0) >= 0)
           counter++;                    

        }
if(counter==0){
alert("Please select atleast one"); return false;
}

Answer (score 1):

maybe you could try add this javascript function to the ADD button onClientClick attribute.

```
            function tryThis() {
        var rowscount = document.getElementById('<%=yourGridViewID.ClientID%>').rows.length;
        var chkTest = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < rowscount-1; i++) {
            var chkName = "yourGridViewID_yourCheckBoxID_" + i;
            var chkChecked = document.getElementById(chkName).checked;
            if (chkChecked == true) {
                chkTest = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (chkTest == 0) {
            alert('Nothing Checked');
        }
        else {
            alert('Something Checked');
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

References:

[How do I get if a checkbox is checked or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754699/how-do-i-get-if-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not)

[ASP.NET GridView row count using Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1763641/asp-net-gridview-row-count-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Add asp.net **CustomValidator** control, and set js function

**HTML Markup:**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" cssClass="chkd" />

<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" ID="validcontrol" EnableClientScript="true"
ClientValidationFunction="validchkbox">required.</asp:CustomValidator>
```

**JavaScript Function:**

```
function validchkbox(sender, e)
{
    e.IsValid = $(".chkd input:checkbox").is(':checked');
}
```

**Code behind:**

```
if (Page.IsValid)
{
    //  Logic Code here...
}
```

---

**OR**

**Jquery** makes life more easy for developer :

```
   if ($('.chkd').is(':checked')){
        alert("Heloo Welcome..");
    } 
   else {
          alert("Please select the checkbox.");
        }
```

**[DEMO JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mAfKc/2/)**

**Note:** here `chkd` is your checkbox class name

Answer (score 0):

let your gridview id is gv_test

than

```
function checkChecked() {
    var count = 0;
    $("#gv_test").find(":checkbox").each(function (i) {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            count++;
        }
    });
    if (count == 0) {
        alert('your error message');
    }
}
```

hope this will work. Thank you.